# I've lost my main Minecraft world, I have a backup of all my files of Minecraft on a USB just how do I get my world back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I was on my Minecraft world when my laptop suddenly shut down. My laptop (that runs Windows 10) has been having problems with faulty battery and keeps shutting down randomly and wont turn back on without the charger even though it's not low on battery.

The next time I went on Minecraft my world was gone but luckily I had a backup of all my files including Minecraft separately all on a USB. The thing is I don't know absolutely *anything* to do with stuff like that and importing maps and I don't know how to get my world back.

I've tried pressing the import world button but I don't know where my world is since all I see is heaps of files in my Minecraft backup if that's even how i get it back.

Also, in the past I've searched how to import maps on Windows 10 and that you go to your `.minecraft` folder and then so on, the thing is I don't have a `.minecraft` folder even though I've done the exact steps to get to that folder it isn't there for me.

So I don't even though how to find my worlds. Can someone please help me and tell me where to find my world and how to get it back?

Comment: Are you playing Java edition or Windows 10/Pocket/Bedrock edition?

Answer (score 4):

and welcome to Arquade!

The first thing you need to do to recover your world is find the `.minecraft` folder. I found my own method of accessing it, since the common "searching `%appdata%` folder" method never seemed to work for me.

Here it is:

1. Open File Explorer.
2. Go to 'View' and check 'Hidden Items'.

[image: Check 'Hidden Items']

3. Go to folder: 'Windows Disk' (May differ in names, for example: `Windows(C:)`)
4. Go to folder: Users and open your user folder (Name of user folder depends your Microsoft Account username)

[image: Open your User file]

5. Open the hidden 'AppData' folder

[image: The 'AppData' folder]

7. Go to folder: 'Roaming'
8. Go to folder: '.minecraft'
9. Open folder 'saves'

[image: The 'saves' folder]

Here you are! Import any world file in this folder and it will appear in-game!
Be careful,though. Do NOT import compressed (.zip) files, as they would not appear in-game.

If you still cannot find your '.minecraft' folder, it doesn't mean you don't have one. A '.minecraft' folder is required for Minecraft, and it should be in this exact location as showcased, as long as you don't have a cracked version or changed the file directory manually while installing.

Comment: Very comprehensive! +1

Comment: FYI you dont "search" `%appdata%`, you open windows explorer and click in the bar at the top where it shows you your current location, then type `%appdata%` there. This will always work.